# Including multiple paths in Django's request.path { if } statement

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a header that belongs on every page except for the home page path and my blog page path, but I can't seem to get an 'or' statement to work.  Any ideas are appreciated.  Thank you.

**This works**

```
{% if request.path != '/' %}
 ...
{% endif %}
```

**This doesn't, but is what I need**

```
{% if request.path != '/' or request.path != '/news' %}
 ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition `request.path != '/' or request.path != '/news'` will always return True (`request.path` will always differ from one or another value). You need to use `and` in your case:

```
{% if request.path != '/' and request.path != '/news' %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Its always the simple things I overlook - thank you.  To get the news path and the post path itself i.e /news/post-url-path, I wrote it as  `{% if request.path != '/' and '/news' not in request.path %} ... {% endif %}`